# Get multiple / dynamic EditText value in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I'm new with these case and I want to try to get the value of dynamic EditText(s) from RecyclerView.

[image: here is the pic example]

And in the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        style="@style/textH4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Ini adalah tempat pertanyaan pertama" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_120sdp"
        android:hint="Tulis jawaban anda"
        style="@style/EdittextPrimary"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_outline_grey"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The question is.. how do I get the EditText value and put it in an ArrayList ?

***Newest update codes :***
I add my Recycler Adapter, and tried these :

```
class RequestJoinAdapter(
    val onTextChanged: (text:String,position:Int)->Unit
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RequestJoinAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var listData: MutableList<KeamananModel> = ArrayList()

    private var textValue = ""

    fun insertAll(data: List<KeamananModel>) {
        data.forEach {
            listData.add(it)
            notifyItemInserted(listData.size - 1)
        }
    }

    fun clear() {
        if (listData.isNotEmpty()) {
            listData.clear()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            ItemRequestJoinBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = listData[position]
        holder.bindTo(item)

        holder.binding.etAnswer.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                onTextChanged.invoke(s.toString(), position)
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                textValue = s.toString().toLowerCase()
            }
        })

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = listData.size

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemRequestJoinBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bindTo(item: KeamananModel) {

            val context = binding.root.context

            binding.tvQuestion.text = item.qt
        }

    }

    private fun isLog(msg: String) {
        Log.e("join grup:", msg)
    }

}
```

and in my current Activity, I used to add some codes like

```
RequestJoinAdapter { text, position ->
            val values = ArrayList<Jawaban>()
            val hashSet = HashSet<Jawaban>()
            values.add(Jawaban(pertanyaan_no = position+1, jawaban = text))
            hashSet.addAll(values)
            values.clear()
            values.addAll(hashSet)
            val valuest = ArrayList<JawabanKeamanan>()
            val hashSets = HashSet<JawabanKeamanan>()
            valuest.add(JawabanKeamanan(values))
            hashSets.addAll(valuest)
            valuest.clear()
            valuest.addAll(hashSets)
            isLog("currentResult: $valuest")
        }
```

How do I set my latest ***valuest*** into my `var listJawaban: MutableList<JawabanKeamanan> = ArrayList()` without any duplicate datas inside it ? What I want is like `JawabanKeamanan(jawaban_keamanan=[Jawaban(pertanyaan_no=1, jawaban=t)], [Jawaban(pertanyaan_no=2, jawaban=u)])`. Thanks..

Comment: Can you post your recycler view adapter?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to implement a `TextWatcher` to your EditText and have it return your data when your text is changed.

Now you may ask how can I get such data in my activty? Well it's pretty simple.
Create an interface in your adapter to communicate with your activity.

Pass your interface as a constructor parameter so when you initialize your adapter in the activity your methods are implemented.

Another solution for you is to add a button in each item of your list and call your interface method in the button's `OnClickListener`.

**EDIT:**
In the snippet below I have used a lambda function for when the text changes.

```
    class RequestJoinAdapter(
      private val onClickedItem: (ArrayList<String>)->Unit,
      val onTextChanged: (text:String,position:Int)->Unit
    ):
      RecyclerView.Adapter<RequestJoinAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    
      var listData: MutableList<KeamananModel> = ArrayList()
    
      var listJawaban: MutableList<Jawaban> = ArrayList()
    
      private var textValue = ""
    
      fun insertAll(data: List<KeamananModel>) {
        data.forEach {
          listData.add(it)
          notifyItemInserted(listData.size - 1)
        }
      }
    
      fun clear() {
        if (listData.isNotEmpty()) {
          listData.clear()
          notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
      }
    
      override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
          ItemRequestJoinBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
          )
        )
      }
    
      override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = listData[position]
        holder.bindTo(item)
    
      }
    
      override fun getItemCount() = listData.size
    
      inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemRequestJoinBinding):
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    
        fun bindTo(item: KeamananModel) {
    
          val context = binding.root.context
    
          binding.tvQuestion.text = item.qt
          
          binding.etAnswer.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
              if (textValue.isNotEmpty()) {
                isLog(textValue)
                
                onTextChanged.invoke(s,absoluteAdapterPosition)
              } else {
    
              }
              listJawaban.add(Jawaban(pertanyaan_no = adapterPosition + 1, jawaban = textValue))
              isLog(listJawaban.toString())
            }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
          textValue = s.toString().toLowerCase()
        }
      })
    }

  }

  private fun isLog(msg: String) {
    Log.e("join grup:", msg)
  }

}
```

Pay attention to the `onTextChanged.invoke()` method. This lambda function can be used like an interface to communicate between your adapter and your view. It will be triggered every time your text is changed.

Finally instantiate your adapter like below:

```
val adapter = RequestJoinAdapter({

    }, { text, position ->
        //onTextChanged
    })
```

The `position` argument is there to help you know which TextView was changed

Comment: `Well it's pretty simple.` no, it isn't, that's why OP is asking about it here. include complete solutions in your answers so that people in future can benefit from this as well

Comment: Dear @a_local_nobody you're absolutely right. I will edit my answer right away! Thanks for the feedback

Comment: These codes are works, but my last question is, how to apply the `val adapter = RequestJoinAdapter({

    }, { text, position ->
        //onTextChanged
    })`
into ArrayList, what I want is like `[Jawaban(pertanyaan_no=1, jawaban=test1), Jawaban(pertanyaan_no=2, jawaban=test2)]` (the **position** depends on the _model_ size)

Comment: @saman I update my question above, and tried something but still confused, hope can help to solve, thanks